# native_window_set_buffers_geometry failed

Tags: android

I am trying to develop a surveillance application in OMAP 4460(Blaze Tablet-in ICS) acting as client device rendering the surveillance feed from a remote source. To begin with,  surveillance feed is streamed remotely from the camera and port forwarded as RTP packets which are received and rendered in OMAP 4460 through a customized RTP stack. While rendering, I am getting the following error from the decoder, saying that "Surface Texture has been abandoned and native_window _set_buffers_geometry failed", more frequently.

Following is the log captured:

```
E/AwesomePlayer(  131): AwesomePlayer::onPrepareAsyncEvent-------- err = 0
E/AwesomePlayer(  131): AwesomePlayer::onPrepareAsyncEvent-------- OK = -430191887
I/OMXCodec(  131): [OMX.TI.DUCATI1.VIDEO.DECODER] AVC profile = 66 (Baseline), level = 31
E/OMXCodec(  131): set buffer size variable to : 307200
I/OMXCodec(  131): [OMX.TI.DUCATI1.VIDEO.DECODER] video dimensions are 640 x 480
I/OMXCodec(  131): [OMX.TI.DUCATI1.VIDEO.DECODER] Crop rect is 640 x 480 @ (0, 0)
E/SurfaceTexture(  128): [SurfaceView] setCrop: SurfaceTexture has been abandoned!
E/SurfaceTextureClient(  131): ISurfaceTexture::setCrop(...) returned No such device
E/SurfaceTexture(  128): [SurfaceView] setLayout: SurfaceTexture has been abandoned!
E/SurfaceTexture(  128): [SurfaceView] setCrop: SurfaceTexture has been abandoned!
E/SurfaceTextureClient(  131): ISurfaceTexture::setCrop(...) returned No such device
E/OMXCodec(  131): native_window_set_buffers_geometry failed: No such device (19)
E/ion     (  131): ioctl -1073460991 failed with code -1: Bad file number
E/ion     (  131): ioctl -1073460991 failed with code -1: Bad file number
D/DOMX    (  131): hardware/ti/domx/domx/omx_proxy_common/src/omx_proxy_common.c:2208    PROXY_ComponentDeInit()    
D/DOMX    (  131): ERROR: failed check:(eError == OMX_ErrorNone) || (eError == OMX_ErrorNoMore) - returning error: 0x80001011 - Error returned from OMX API in ducati
D/DOMX    (  131): hardware/ti/domx/omx_core/src/OMX_Core.c:396    OMX_FreeHandle()    
D/DOMX    (  131): ERROR: Error From ComponentDeInit..
D/StackInterface(  131): AwesomePlayer::reset_l called ++
```

SDP of the camera:

```
v=0

o=StreamingServer 3331435948 1116907222000 IN IP4 192.168.1.102

s=h264.mp4

c=IN IP4 239.0.0.00;/1

t=0 0

a=control:*

m=video 0 RTP/AVP 96

a=control:trackID=0

a=rtpmap:96 H264/90000

a=fmtp:96 packetization-mode=1; sprop-parameter-sets=Z0KAH9oCgPSbgIEAmBAAfQAAEZQve+Eg,aM48gA==

m=application 0 RTP/AVP 107

a=control:trackID=2

a=rtpmap:107 vnd.onvif.metadata/90000
```

I have been trying to fix this issue for sometime now, and could not able to find out the problem yet.

Kindly, reveal how to proceed further on the issue.

Regards,

Manoj

Answer (score 0):

My English is not good.

Check SurfaceTexture pointer.
If you define sp<.....> in function, sp<.....> is abandoned with end of function.